# Expo react-native app crashes right after launch in Test Flight

Tags: ios, react-native, meteor, expo, testflight

I have an expo app and trying to do my first release in TestFlight. The app is built successfully in the eas servers and then delivered to Apple for deployment. Everything goes well until I download and open the app: After only like 2 seconds of rendering the register/login page, it just goes immediately blank white. I could not have found a way to address the issue or debug.

Locally, I have no problem using the app either.

I have found out that the crash is due to connecting the Meteor server and its consequences (code below). The app first renders fine, just have problem after logging in.

Here's the code of the entire app: https://github.com/eminx/librellarn/blob/main/App.js

```
import Meteor, { useTracker } from '@meteorrn/core';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
Meteor.connect('wss://myapp.com/websocket', { AsyncStorage });
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "librella",
    "slug": "librella-app",
    "version": "0.1.4",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.eminx.librella",
      "buildNumber": "0.1.4"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow Librella to use your location."
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "some-id"
      }
    },
    "owner": "eminx"
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "librellarn",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build:ios": "eas build --platform ios",
    "build:android": "eas build --platform android",
    "submit:ios": "eas submit -p ios",
    "submit:android": "eas submit -p android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@gluestack-style/react": "^1.0.30",
    "@gluestack-ui/config": "^1.0.10",
    "@gluestack-ui/themed": "^1.0.33",
    "@meteorrn/core": "^2.7.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1530.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "~1.5.12",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "lucide-react-native": "^0.279.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.46.1",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Have you gone over Expo's docs on troubleshooting production issues?  https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/runtime-issues/#production-errors

Comment: @GregFenton Just did but no success... It works perfectly fine with the production mode locally. The problem is with the connection to the server with the `Meteor.connect(wss://myapp.com/websocket)` code, which surprisingly works quite fine locally but on the testflight.

Comment: Does it not throw an exception?  What if you don't specify the {AsyncStorage} option to `.connect()` ?

Comment: Have you considered asking on the Meteor Discord Server?  I'm not sure how well Meteor & Expo (or RN) are being used or supported.  The Expo/RN page on Meteor's documentation hasn't been updated in 3 years (and is woefully out of date....dreadfully wrong about Expo's limitations)

Comment: Thank you @GregFenton! Yes I tried without the AsyncStorage. Same thing.. :/

Comment: I'm in touch with the person maintaining the library, and he's being really helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/meteorrn/meteor-react-native/issues/141

Comment: Excellent!  I have also pointed out some of the out-of-date information in their documentation when it comes to Expo.  Someone has offered to do a PR to their docs in the coming days.

Comment: sounds great. thanks a lot for your efforts! I'll update here when I get to know the reason of the crash.

Comment: @GregFenton maintainer here, please open the issue regarding outdated Expo information, I am eager to review and merge.

Comment: @Jankapunkt - someone from the Expo team should be reaching out. Feel free to contact me directly if you want to discuss more.  first dot last at gmail dot com.

Comment: Thank you@GregFenton! Indeed I have figured it out by successfully building and running locally. I'll give the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to build and run it locally in the Xcode Simulator, which is somehow different than the Expo simulator. Then it was very simple fixes of installing a few packages, like the `react-native-svg` etc.

The ios building locally was not easy dealing with Cocoa Pods etc, but at the end, I managed to do it successfully and therefore could access the error console for debugging. Furthermore, I could then also upload directly to the App Store, bypassing the need to use EAS (Expo cloud build service)...